# How to enter mathematics equations in asp.net and save equation to SQL Server for my online test

Tags: asp.net

I want to take math equations from user interface like a textbox and save them to SQL Server.

Is there any possible way please suggest me. I found like creating images but it not  possible for my project which needs to create lot and user did not have that much of knowledge in creating images and me too.

Please help me like binding virtual keyboard to textbox or other possible ways

NMaheshGoud

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/) if I were you. It would require a custom control to allow the user to enter the data. Unfortunately the .Net editor appears to no longer be available but you could resort to a Flash-based one such as [fmath Editor](http://www.fmath.info/editor/download.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you save it in a nvarchar field?

Assuming you are allowing text input then save it as this base form?

Comment: yes i  can store  how  to take sigma,chemistry type questions from user .this needs a control to accept such type symbols to enter .

Answer (score 0):

I've published a JavaScript library that you can use to create a virtual math keyboard. It is intended for use together with any LaTeX typesetting library (for example MathJax or KaTeX).

GitHub repository: https://github.com/MathKeyboardEngine/MathKeyboardEngine 
Live examples: https://mathkeyboardengine.github.io

I see that you want to store the user's input in a database. Call `getViewModeLatex` to get the user's input as a LaTeX string (for example `\frac{x}{1-x}`) that you can store.